# Fetch Apache Pulsar unacknowledged messages

Tags: c#, websocket, apache-pulsar

I have a persistent topic in Pulsar which has 200 messages. The first 100 messages are acknowledged but the rest of them are not. I am using WebSockets to connect to Pulsar topics to read them.

**Here is my question:**
When I create a new *Reader* it does not seem to fetch the 100 messages that were not unacknowledged. It will only fetch new messages that were queued after making the reader.

How can I retrieve the old unacknowledged messages by using a reader? This setup works when I use a *Consumer*.

Comment: When the reader is created, you can specify a startMessageId where the message can be read from. If it only fetch new messages were queued after making the reader, did you specify MessageId.latest in the startMessageId?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your messages are in backlog we can always check the stats of the topic and try changing the subscription name.
And Instead of using Web-socket using pulsar client node is lot ore easier everything is documented in the apache pulsar docs.